# Switching JavaStreamingContext from INITIALIZED to ACTIVE

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm using the example code proposed by Spark Streaming "JavaKafkaWordCount.java".

```js
  

public final class JavaKafkaWordCount {
  private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

  private JavaKafkaWordCount() {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: JavaKafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
    // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] topics = args[2].split(",");
    for (String topic: topics) {
      topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);

    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
        .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

    wordCounts.print();
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
  }
}
```

After creating the `SparkConf` object, it creates the `JavaStreamingContext`.
Then it defines all the functions needed to do the WordCount, and it starts the `JavaStreamingContext`. After that, it never comes back to `wordCount.print()`but it keeps printing. How is that possible? What happens when the JSSC switches from INITIALIZED to ACTIVE? Is it a loop or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, Spark Streaming uses a scheduler to execute all registered 'output operations'.

'output operations' are operations that cause the materialization of the declared stream transformations which are lazy like in Spark.
In the particular case of the code in the question, `wordCounts.print();` is such 'output operation' and it will be registered in the Spark Streaming scheduler, causing it to execute at each 'batch interval'. The 'batch interval' is defined at the moment the Streaming Context is created. Going back to the code above: `new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));` the 'batch interval' 
 is 2000ms or 2 seconds.

**In a nutshell:**

Each 2 seconds, Spark Streaming will trigger the execution of `wordCounts.print()` which in turn materializes the evaluation of the DStream with the data for that interval. The materialization process will apply all defined transformations on the DStream (and underlying RDD), such as the `map`, `flatMap` and `mapToPair` operations in the same code.

Comment: thank you so much, this made me understand everything.

Comment: @sirdan You are welcome! Also, you could try removing `wordCounts.print();` from your example and attempt to run it. It will complain that there are no output operations registered, so it has nothing to do.

Comment: It happened just like you said. It promps and error which states that no output action are required.